# i can't connect the php modbus TCP

Tags: php, modbus

this is my code, i use ModbusMaster.php  to test connect modbus,but i can't connect

```
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../vendor/adduc/phpmodbus/Phpmodbus/ModbusMaster.php'; 
     // Modbus master UDP
     $IP =  '192.168.0.1' ;
    $RAM_location =  '32769';
    $RAM_NUM = '10' ;
    // // Create Modbus object
    $modbus = new ModbusMaster($IP, "TCP");

 // Read multiple registers
 try {  
     $recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(0, $RAM_location, $RAM_NUM);
 }
 catch (Exception $e) {
     // Print error information if any
     echo $modbus;
     echo $e;
     exit;
 }
 // Print data in string format
 echo PhpType::bytes2string($recData);
?>
```

but if i use test  test software can get the data

[image]

this is my error message

[image]

thx

---

I'll try to replace 0 with 1

It still doesn't work.

And I confirmed that I am connected to the same device and also pinged

code

```
  $IP =  '192.168.0.1' ;
    $RAM_location =  '32769';
    $RAM_NUM = '10' ;
    // // Create Modbus object
    $modbus = new ModbusMaster($IP, "TCP");

 // Read multiple registers
 try {  
     $recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(1, $RAM_location, $RAM_NUM);
 }
 catch (Exception $e) {
     // Print error information if any
     echo $modbus;
     echo $e;
     exit;
 }
 // Print data in string format
 echo PhpType::bytes2string($recData);
```

error message

[image]
ping

[image]

---

By the way, I tried to open the Modbus server test software

It says that there is a problem with my 502port.

But I use netstat to check 502 port is not occupied.

Does it have anything to do with the fact that I can't connect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please try `readMultipleRegisters(1, 32768, 10)` (I believe that should generate the same request as your EasyModbus example). If that does not work then please confirm that your code is running on the same machine as your EasyModbus test and provide a bit of info about the device you are attempting to query.

Comment: @Brits It still doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: I changed two things. Try as per my comment (address = 32768). Based on the updated error I'd expect that to work. Re 'modbus Poll' the screenshot shows a different address (127.0.0.1) which is probably the issue there...

Comment: 127.0.0.1 just local test software, i want connect is 192.168.0.1 .
[address  = 32768] can get 「C」  but data is 「ABC」,   and  if  i set 1  form RAM_NUM  i get 「AB」

Comment: 67 in ASCII is "C" and that's the first result in your EasyModbus screenshot so that seems to be working as expected. It looks like the issue you raised is resolved; if you have another issue I'd suggest a new question (because different info will be needed).

Comment: OK , I got it.   but my address is  32769~33304。  this code can get  one address's data (10word) but if i set RAM_NUM  > 10   the error message appears again.

Comment: That's probably a limitation with the device you are communicating with (which you have not identified so I can't really comment).

Comment: OK Thanks for your help, I'm trying to see. But can you tell me the difference between 1 and 0 in 「readMultipleRegisters(1, 32768, 10)」?
Because I was able to catch the value I wanted with 0 on another device before.

Comment: It's confusing (0 and 1 can mean the same thing in different packages). Suggest reading "Modbus: When 40001 Really Means 1, or 0 Really Means 1" section in [this article](https://www.csimn.com/CSI_pages/Modbus101.html).

Comment: OK, and why i can't  get you 「Answer」

Comment: Sorry - I misread your previous comment. The first parameter to readMultipleRegisters is the Unit Identifier. This often not meaningful with ModbusTCP (because generally each device has its own IP) but sometimes, especially with ModbusTCP -> RTU gateways, this determines which subunit the request is for (a gateway might have multiple Modbus RTU units behind it). Anyway the upside of this is that use of the UnitID is device dependent...

Comment: I get the all data now, thx your help.

Answer (score -1):

try the ModbusMasterTcp-Class to get your Object-Instance:

```
new ModbusMasterTcp($ip, "TCP")
```